# startActivityForResult() on selecting Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

Is it possible to use startActivityForResult() from a status bar notification?

Say I have an activity A, which on some event starts activity B using startActivityForResult(). Now when it is in the background, on the event it shows a notification. Now on selecting the notification, how do i start activity B for result?

I do realize that activity A should have a service that runs in the background, but i guess the same question would apply even in that case.

Here's the code for the notification. This is in the Activity A.

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "New Notification", System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "My Notification Title";
    CharSequence contentText = "My Notification Text";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    nm.notify(1, notification);  //1 = id
```

Comment: if it is in a notification, which activity would get the result? Consider that the notification does not belong to the activity does has created it.

Comment: @herschel The notification is created from Activity A, so i assumed that Activity A would get the result in its onActivityResult() method. Is that wrong anyway?

Comment: Yes I think it is wrong. The Activity A may not be there anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should just start the activity A from the activity B when the activity B is opened by opening the notification and then closed.
You can pass the return value in the intent that you use to start the activity A from the activity B.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use startActivityForResult. You can achieve the same functionality in different way.
Pass the result as an extra with your notification. Get this result in onResume of activity B.